# Retopology of Cloth from Marvelous Designer

Tags: modeling

Is it necessary to retopologize triangulated cloth coming from marvelous designer?

I noticed that cloth coming from MD is triangulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually create it quadrangulated inside of Marvelous. Otherwise, you will need to retopo it yes (depending on your needs)

Comment: I didn't know you could export it already quadrangulated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your 3D mesh inside of MD, you can choose Quandrangulate or Remesh. Try that out. It isnt an export feature but something you do in the simulation panel. In my opinion, even such mesh requires retopology, if your plan is to use it in a game